# Should I keep adding conditions to my LINQ query or add a condition upfront and use two different queries?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ Query:

```
 var contents = _contentsRepository.GetAll()
            .Where(a => a.SubjectId == subjectId && 
                   a.ContentTypeId == contentTypeId && 
                   a.ContentStatusId == contentStatusId )
            .ToList();
```

I would like this select to proceed normally unless the contentStatusId == 99. If that's 
the case then I want it to retrieve a row from the database with ANY contentStatusId.

Would it be best to do a check of contentStatusId first and then break this down into
two LINQ selects or is there a way I could modify my LINQ query?

Note that I am using SQL Server 2012 and my repository:

public virtual IQueryable GetAll() { return DbSet; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can modify your query by adding a `contentStatusId == 99` component to your predicate that will short-circuit the evaluation of `a.ContentStatusId == contentStatusId` like so:

```
var contents = _contentsRepository.GetAll()
            .Where(a => a.SubjectId == subjectId && 
                   a.ContentTypeId == contentTypeId && 
                   (contentStatusId == 99 ||
                    a.ContentStatusId == contentStatusId))
            .ToList();
```

In the normal case everything will work just like before.

In the case when `contentStatusId` equals 99, there will be overhead of evaluating `contentStatusId == 99` for every row, although I think depending on repository you're querying this part could be inlined as a `true`. You should see for yourself how this impacts performance in your setup.

Comment: Do you think this would have any impact on performance of the generated SQL or would it all happen before the SQL was generated?

Comment: My repository returns an IQueryable and is connected to SQL Server 2012. Does that give any more insight into possible performance problems? public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return DbSet;
        }

Comment: @Melina, this will most likely not be optimized during generation of SQL query (but you should check with `db.GetCommand(query).CommandText`), but I believe it should be optimized by the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var contents = _contentsRepository.GetAll()
        .Where(a => contentStatusId == 99 ? (a.SubjectId == subjectId && 
               a.ContentTypeId == contentTypeId && 
               a.ContentStatusId == contentStatusId) : (a.SubjectId == subjectId && 
               a.ContentTypeId == contentTypeId) )
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Aaron. I still want the other selects in place if contentStatusId == 99.

Comment: Revised my answer, now if the contentStatusId== 99, it will try to match the three columns. else, only match subjectId and contentTypeId

Answer (score 0):

```
var contents = _contentsRepository.GetAll()             
                                  .Where(a => 
                                  {
                                      return a.ContentTypeId == 99 ||
                                      (a.SubjectId == subjectId && 
                                      a.ContentTypeId == contentTypeId && 
                                      a.ContentStatusId == contentStatusId)
                                  }
```

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear. If the contentStatusId is 99 I still want to be able to select by subjectId and contentTypeID.